# Oracle: split strings

Tags: sql, oracle, split

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
...
IS
l_count binary_integer;
l_array dbms_utility.lname_array;
BEGIN

...

dbms_utility.comma_to_table
  ( list   => regexp_replace(l_input,'(^|,)','\1x')
  , tablen => l_count
  , tab    => l_array
 );

for i in 1 .. l_count
     loop
        myQuery := myQuery || '''' || substr(l_array(i ),2) || '''';
        if i < l_count then
             myQuery := myQuery || ',';
       end if;
     end loop;
...
END;
```

and when I submit a string like this 'aaa,bbb,ccc' it works fine but with not with this one  'aaa,bb/b,ccc' because of the slash character.

Is a there a solution to this problem ? or a different way to do ?

Comment: You can use a replace function to remove the '/' character.

Comment: See [Split single comma delimited string into rows in Oracle](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/12/02/split-comma-delimited-string-into-rows-in-oracle/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `REPLACE` function.

```
''' || REPLACE('aaa,bb/b,ccc', ',','' '') || ''';
```

Output:

```
'aaa' 'bb/b' 'ccc'
```

e.g.

```
''' || REPLACE(@string, ',','' '') || ''';
```

Comment: i dont want to replace this caracter. because i need the whole word (bb/b).
 so the result of the split will be : 'aaa' 'bb/b' 'ccc'

Comment: do you want the output to be 'aaa' 'bb/b' 'ccc'  or 'aaa','bb/b','ccc'

Comment: updated to give `'aaa' 'bb/b' 'ccc'` as output

Comment: @kkung Did you see the topic marked as duplicate? There are multiple options provided to achieve the desired output.

Comment: @LalitKumarB Partially my fault as i responded and edited my answer, which to their defense, was answered before it was marked as duplicate.

Comment: No problem @Matt. OP should be able to get the solution.

Comment: I try it but it doesn't resolve my problem with slash caracter. Plus, I need to iterate over the string to get values one by one.